# how to access invisible cells of parent class collection view in child class in objective c

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When I m trying to access the parent class cell through child class by calling  its method it crashes, because only visible cell of `collectionview` are in queue but `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for invisible cells are `nil`

Here is the code for my child class:

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(self.collectionView.visibleCells())

    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells() {
        let collectionViewCell = cell as! PSMediaCell
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(collectionViewCell)!
        let  imageObj:NSMutableDictionary = imageArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as! NSMutableDictionary

        // this is calling parent class method
        mediavc.mymethodforback(indexPath, vc: self)

        if imageObj.objectForKey("image_url")?.rangeOfString("mov").length > 0 {
        } else {
            var imageView:UIImageView = collectionViewCell.contentView.viewWithTag(122) as! UIImageView
             imagev = imageView
            let indicatorView:UIActivityIndicatorView = collectionViewCell.contentView.viewWithTag(233) as! UIActivityIndicatorView
            var videoIcon:UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(133) as! UIImageView
            var imageOverlay:UIImageView = collectionViewCell.contentView.viewWithTag(234) as! UIImageView
            //var videoIcon:UIImageView = collectionViewCell.contentView.viewWithTag(133) as! UIImageView
            var downloadingFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageObj.objectForKey("image_url") as! String)
            let imageN = UIImage(contentsOfFile:downloadingFilePath as String )
            if imageN == nil {
                var downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
                var downloadingFilePath1 = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageObj.objectForKey("image_url") as! String)
                let downloadingFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: downloadingFilePath1)
                downloadRequest.bucket = "photosharebucket1"
                downloadRequest.key = imageObj.objectForKey("image_url") as! String
                downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL
                self.download(downloadRequest, ImageObj:imageObj)
                indicatorView.hidden = false
                imageOverlay.hidden  = false
            } else {
                imageView.image = imageN
                indicatorView.hidden = true
                imageOverlay.hidden  = true
                videoIcon.hidden  = true
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

This is code of parent class:

```
func mymethodforback(images:NSIndexPath , vc :PSUserSentPhotoDetailsVC) {
    print( images.row)
    print(PSMediaDetailVC.collection.visibleCells().count)
    var cell :PSMediaCollectionViewCell = PSMediaDetailVC.collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(images) as! PSMediaCollectionViewCell  

    // here i m getting nil because cell for particular indexpath is not visible in parent class
    var imageView:UIImageView = cell.imagevieww as UIImageView
    PSMediaDetailVC.imageve = imageView
    print("xcxcxcxc")
    print( PSMediaDetailVC.imageve)
    print(PSMediaDetailVC.collection)
    print(self)
    self.ysl_addTransitionDelegate(PSMediaDetailVC.collection)
    self.navigationController(PSMediaDetailVC.nvc, animationControllerForOperation: UINavigationControllerOperation.Push, fromViewController: self, toViewController:vc )
    // self.ysl_pushTransitionAnimationWithToViewControllerImagePointY(0, animationDuration: 0.3)        
}
```

Comment: first of all that is not objective c at least the code that you have posted

Comment: i used objective c tag here becz if i get code solution in objective c i can change that in swift

Answer (score 1):

The cells in a `UICollectionView` display information from the underlying data model, they don't store information in their own right.  As a result, there is no need for cells that aren't currently onscreen to held in memory; they can easily be recreated by calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just before they are needed.  This enables the collection view to reuse cell objects and reduce its memory footprint.

The result of all this is that you cannot get cells that are not currently displayed by calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath` on the collection view.

Comment: but actually i need to perform facebook ios app  imageviewer type animation i.e. when open the pic and scroll it and when we pan the pic to down its goes to that pic which is opened ...... here in above code  in child class i scrollled to that pic which is not in the parents frame , so how i can access that imageview which is out of parents's frame

Comment: can we copy the same animation functionality between two view controllers , which is in facebbok ios app i.e. when we open the pic and slide down to go back page

Comment: So, if I understand, you want to be able to transition back to a cell in the collection view that wasn't on screen when you displayed the image?  If so the you could try scrolling the collectionview to that indexPath before you start the transition

Comment: ohk !! but how i scroll the collection view of parent viewcontroller when i am scrolling collectionview of child view controller !! plzzz suggest

Comment: Use a delegate pattern

Comment: u means, i sud create @protocol  in child view controller and implement that in parent class , and in that protocol method i sud scroll collection view of parent class , 
 will it really scroll the collection view of parent  and make invisible cell of parent view controller visible ??  

but how we get to know whether they are scrolled or not becz we are on child viewcontroller

Comment: plzzz suggest  i have implemented , but not getting the solution